# Python 3 string represented with hex escapes

Tags: python

In Python2, string was originally represented with hex escapes:

```
>>> "你好，世界。"
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\xef\xbc\x8c\xe4\xb8\x96\xe7\x95\x8c\xe3\x80\x82'
```

How do I print it in Python 3?

Comment: `"你好，世界。".encode('u8')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.encode()`

```py
>>> "你好，世界。".encode()
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\xef\xbc\x8c\xe4\xb8\x96\xe7\x95\x8c\xe3\x80\x82'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
print("你好，世界。".encode('utf-8'))
```